# Reactjs - Following tutorial but getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, babeljs

I'm new to React, Nodejs etc and am unable to get a simple web page running. Could someone be kind enough to help?

The error is (from browser console) ...

```
Inline Babel script:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:14
    at _ve (transformScriptTags.ts:99:10)
    at n (transformScriptTags.ts:173:9)
    at Ove (transformScriptTags.ts:221:3)
    at transformScriptTags.ts:257:3
    at Xve (index.ts:230:3)
    at qve (index.ts:214:3)
```

My index.html is ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="gpsaustrack.webmanifest">

    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>         
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-div"></div>
        <script type="text/jsx">
            import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
            const app = document.getElementById('main-div');
            const root = createRoot(app);
            root.render(<h1>Develop. Preview. Ship. </h1>);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Apache httpd web server running on Oracle Linux 8. For some reason I'm also running ...
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod --presets=@babel/preset-env
I think this is supposed to do the conversion work from JSX to Javascript.

I would also like to put the Javascript into a file but when I try that I get a syntax error on the "<" on the root.render line and that'll be due to not being able to specify type="text/jsx" so I don't think Babel knows to translate it. Could anyone explain this?

I'm working through the React tutorial as well as the Next tutorial as well as the Nodejs tutorial but I'm now a bit stuck! Thanks in advance for any help.

I tried searching for others with the same error, but was unable to find help. People refer to using Webpack or Commonjs or similar additional libraries but I can't think why they would be necessary. I don't want to add more and more stuff without reason.